# Custom TFS 2015 Build Activity with output variable

Tags: tfs, build, sonarqube, tfs-2015

Is there a way with the new build system in TFS 2015 to pass an output parameter from a build activity?

I currently would like to set the variable used for the Begin SonarQube Task to be the assembly version value in the AssemblyInfo.cs file. I can easily get the value, but I don't see a way to pass that information back to the build process to use in the next step. Currently I need to remember to update the value in the build definition.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [task output command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set variables from powershell tasks

Something like this:

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"

Comment: Thanks that did it. I guess I just wasn't searching on the right thing.